# Http 404 while adding MS teams app in channel

Tags: microsoft-teams, 404

I am trying to learn MS Teams app development. I am following [this](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/sbs-gs-spfx?tabs=vscode%2Cviscode) link for the same. But when I run the app with local debug in teams toolkit, I am getting 404 error when it is trying to create new tab. I have enabled sideloading. I can see the app in teams personal tab working. The issue occurs only in Teams tab set up. Please see below screenshot for the same:

[image]

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was a silly mistake. We need to publish the app to add it in teams channel tab. Local debug can showcase you the outcome in the teams personal tab only.